# Background Image is not being Displayed

Tags: html, css, mobile

This is the first time I am making a mobile application. I am using Dreamweaver. The background image is not being displayed.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body class="main-page">

    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS file

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body.main-page 
{
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url (images/home_main.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: use `background-image: url('images/home_main.jpg');` also make sure the url is correct. Test it with the whole url starting with `http://` if you are not sure.

Comment: @RST seems that the image are in the website directory because he has wrote a relative path.

Comment: Please don't ask 2 questions in one box.

Comment: @leoMestizo that is just what I mean, sometimes files are not referred to the right way when using relative path. When images don't show up it would be my first place to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the space between the *url value* and the parenthesis:

```
background: url("Your url");
```

Here's a DEMO with the above CSS rule: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/leoMestizo/9z2zV/1/).

Instead of:

```
background: url ("Your url");
```

And here's a DEMO with this other CSS rule: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/leoMestizo/9z2zV/).